# plt.tight_layout buggy with long titles?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**The problem:**

How come every `plt.tight_layout()` shrinks the figure a bit more even after a fresh start with `plt.clf()`?

Take this snippet:

```
plt.figure(1).clf()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.title("Blah")
plt.tight_layout()

for _ in range(5):
    plt.figure(2).clf()
    plt.plot(range(10))
    plt.title("Blah")
    plt.tight_layout()
```

As expected figures 1 and 2 are identical.

But now make the title very long:

```
plt.figure(3).clf()
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.title("Blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
plt.tight_layout()

for _ in range(5):
    plt.figure(4).clf()
    plt.plot(range(10))
    plt.title("Blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
    plt.tight_layout()
```

and figures 3 and 4 are non longer identical, figure 4 being shrunk horizontally  and this shrinkage increases with the number of loops.

If someone can shed some light on this...

**Some background info:**

You might ask "Why on earth would you put such plotting stuff in a `for` loop?". I actually don't but I have an interactive script where I may replot the same figure several times with some variation, and this shrinkage appears just the same...

My python version is:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

And BTW, if you increase the number of `plt.tight_layout()` calls enough, you eventually get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-89-1a59da108bdf>", line 5, in <module>
    plt.tight_layout()

  File "C:\Users\julien.bernu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1379, in tight_layout
    fig.tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)

  File "C:\Users\julien.bernu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1756, in tight_layout
    self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\julien.bernu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1612, in subplots_adjust
    self.subplotpars.update(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\julien.bernu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 226, in update
    raise ValueError('left cannot be >= right')

ValueError: left cannot be >= right
```

Comment: Simply don't use `tight_layout` several times on the same figure. It will always 'optimize' a bit until you reach a very unpleasant result.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sure but `tight_layout` is otherwise quite convenient. And the figure is cleared at each iteration so the optimization should be the same every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are clearing the figure, the figure keeps its SubplotParams, which have been adjusted by the call to `tight_layout`.

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

left = []; right = []
def print_subplotparams(sp):
    t = "left={left:.3f}, right={right:.3f}, top={top:.3f}, bottom={bottom:.3f}"
    t = t.format(left=sp.left, right=sp.right, top=sp.top, bottom=sp.bottom)
    left.append(sp.left); right.append(sp.right)
    print(t)

fig = plt.figure(1)
print_subplotparams(fig.subplotpars)
fig.clear()

for _ in range(8):
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    # uncomment to see difference
    #fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, right=0.900, top=0.880, bottom=0.110)
    plt.plot(range(10))
    plt.title("Blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh")
    plt.tight_layout()
    print_subplotparams(fig.subplotpars)
    fig.clear()

fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(5,3))
plt.plot(range(len(left)), left, label="left")
plt.plot(range(len(right)), right, label="right")
plt.title("SubplotParams left/right as function of calls to tight_layout")
plt.xlabel("number of call to tight_layout")
plt.ylabel("left/right parameter")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

As can be seen, in each loop step `tight_layout` adjusts from the already adjusted paramters and makes them even smaller.

To prevent that one might reset the SubplotParams in each step

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, right=0.900, top=0.880, bottom=0.110)
```

In this case `tight_layout` always optimizes starting with the same initial parameters and their final values will not change.

[image]